# Calculate correlation between different effect sizes retrieved from individual studies in meta-analysis

Tags: correlation, meta-analysis, effect-size

I am working on a meta-analysis where i have two different effect sizes for each study (2 variables A and B that are measured after a specific treatment). I can run two different meta-analysis on these effect sizes, but this doesn't allow me to explore the relationship between the two effect sizes. I would like to know if, for example, a high effect size for A would also imply a high effect size for B.

Specifically, im working in ecology and I my research question is wether organic agriculture improves bee abundance, and if so, if this leads to higher yields. So for each study i have an effect size for bee abundance, and an effect size for yield. Are there any options to explore the relationship between these two effect sizes? Would it be correct to just apply correlation analysis on these effect sizes?